# Root of the polynomial $\begin{bmatrix}t-a&-b\\-c&t-d\end{bmatrix}=(t-a)(t-d)-bc$ an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

> 1.Let $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix in a field $K$. Show that any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of this matrix is a root of the polynomial
>   $\begin{bmatrix}t-a&-b\\-c&t-d\end{bmatrix}=(t-a)(t-d)-bc$.
>
> 2. Conversely, show that any root of the polynomial $\begin{bmatrix}t-a&-b\\-c&t-d\end{bmatrix}=(t-a)(t-d)-bc$ is an eigenvalue of the given matrix.
>      ***Linear Algebra, Serge Lang***

It was easy to prove 1), I used $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ to get the polynomial expression. But I have know ideia how to do the converse.
1.
$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}ax+by\\cx+dy\end{bmatrix}$

In which  $ax+by=t x$  and $cx+dy=t y$

$\det\begin{bmatrix}t-a&b\\c&t-d\end{bmatrix}=(t-a)(t-d)-ab$

**Question**:

How do I prove 2.? May I use $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote your matrix with $A$. Suppose $\lambda$ is a root of $\chi(t) = \det(tI - A) = (t-a)(t-d)-bc$, then $\det(\lambda I - A) = 0$ and hence $\lambda I - A$ is singular. We therefore have that $\ker(\lambda I - A)$ is nonzero, hence there exist $v \in V$ such that $(\lambda I-A)v = 0$ or $Av = \lambda v$. Hence $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.